# Не работает таймер в linux

Tags: c, linux

Здравствуйте!

Не получается реализовать тайм-аут при помощи сигнала "будильника" SIGALRM. Вообщем есть примерно такое задание: программа, которая ожидает ввода имени с клавиатуры, печатает "Привет, <имя>" и завершается. Если имя не было введено в течение пяти секунд, то программа печатает "Время истекло" и завершается.

1. Не могу понять, как read-ом считать данные с клавиатуры. Он вроде из файла только читает. Но это пол беды.
2. Как при рабочем read услышать будильник... Как-то errno обработать??

Вот что смог сделать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

void funcobr(int snumber)
{
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sigact;
    memset(&sigact, 0, sizeof(sigact));
    sigact.sa_handler = funcobr;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sigact, NULL);
    char str[20];
    alarm(5);

    scanf("%c", &str);
    char y[20] << errno;
    if (errno == "EINTR")
        exit(1);

    printf("%sn", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Alerr, этот код не странслируется.

    scanf("%c", &str);
    char y[20] << errno;
    if (errno == "EINTR")

по крайней мере в этих строчках

Услышать будильник - пишете код 007 на stdout;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. С клавиатуры надо считывать через файловый дескриптор 0:

   ```
   read (0, buf, buf_size);
   ```

2 . Можно все это разнести по разным нитям.

Comment: Спасибо! разобрался)

Comment: @mikillskegg, а зачем по потокам разносить? Можно просто `write()`-ом прямо из обработчика пищать. 

Кстати, если вместо `alarm()` использовать `setitimer()`, то можно задать интервал повтора сигнала.

Comment: @avp, ну в общем, да, можно и без потоков обойтись. Я не очень сразу разобрался в деле и понял по-другому )))